# java saving jpanel issue with imported image

Tags: java

i know there is similar problems to this, but not exactly this,
i am saving the jpanel fine, however i have some images i have imported into the program which paint fine on to the jpanel, but the same images that are painted onto the panel are not saving in the bufferedImage, any suggestions?

i might add i have tryed saving the jpanel directly, but i keeps saving the start image of the jpanel and not the updated one with the game screen, if you have any advice on what im doing wrong there that would be great also.

my code:

Main Class

```
public class WhackAMole extends JFrame implements Sprites{

    Board board = new Board();
    
    public WhackAMole(){
       
        this.setSize(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setTitle("Whack-A-Mole");
        this.add(board);
        this.addMouseListener(board);
  
        
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                
                new WhackAMole().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
}
...
```

My Jpanel Class

```
package whackamole;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author hutch
 */
public class Board extends JPanel implements Sprites, MouseListener{
    
    Clouds[] clouds = new Clouds[4];   
    static MoleHill[] moleHill = new MoleHill[12];
    static Mole mole;
    
    private JButton start;
    private JLabel scoreBoardLabel;
    private JLabel countDownLabel;
    
    private ImageIcon ii;
    private Image title;
    
    private ImageIcon ii2;
    private Image scoreBoard;
    
    private int score;
    private int countdown = 3;
    
    private boolean gameScreen;
    private boolean inGame;
    
    private int levelSpeed = 10;
    
    private File backGroundFile = new File("Background.png");
   
    public Board(){
        
        this.setLayout(null);
        
        ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Title.png"));
        title = ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(500, 110, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        
        ii2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ScoreBoard.png"));
        scoreBoard = ii2.getImage().getScaledInstance(270, 150, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
               
        scoreBoardLabel = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        scoreBoardLabel.setBounds(330, 215, 115 , 80);
        scoreBoardLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
        scoreBoardLabel.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
     
        countDownLabel = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        countDownLabel.setBounds(330, 215, 115 , 80);
        countDownLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 45));
        countDownLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                
        start = new JButton("START");
        start.setBounds(300, 400, 180 , 60);
        start.setFocusPainted(false);
        start.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
        start.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
               
        start.setBackground(new Color(102,68,0));
        start.addActionListener(new play());

        this.add(start);
        
        this.setSize(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);
        initiateClouds();
        initiateMoleHills();
    
    }
    
    public Image background(){
        
        Image image = null;
        
        try {
            
            image = ImageIO.read(backGroundFile).getScaledInstance(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            
            Logger.getLogger(Board.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        return image;
    }
    
    
    /**
     * initiates cloud array
     */
    
    public final void initiateClouds(){

        for(int i =0 ; i < clouds.length; i++){
            
            clouds[i] = new Clouds(0,0);

        }        
    }
    
     /**
     * initiates mole array
     */
    
    public final void initiateMoleHills(){

        int y = 420;
        int x = 135;
        int width = -10;
        int height = 35;
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++){
            
            moleHill[i] = new MoleHill(x, y, width, height);
                          
            x += 120;
                                                               
        }    
        
        y = 570;
        x = 75;
        width = 20;
        height = 50;
        
        for(int j = 4 ; j < 8; j++){
            
            moleHill[j] = new MoleHill(x, y, width, height);
                
            x += 160;
                                                               
        } 
        
        y = 780;
        x = 15;
        width = 50;
        height = 80;
        
        for(int k = 8 ; k < 12; k++){
            
            moleHill[k] = new MoleHill(x, y, width, height);
                
            x += 190;
                                                               
        }     
    }
    
    /**
     *
     * @param g
     */
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        startScreen(g);
            
        
        if(gameScreen == true){
            
            gameScreen(g);          
                      
        }
        if(inGame == true && gameScreen == true){

            playing(g);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * painting the start screen
     * @param g
     */
    
    public void startScreen(Graphics g){
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        this.setBackground(new Color(128,191,255));     //blue sky
        drawTitle(g);
       
        
    }
    
        
    /**
     * painting the game screen
     * @param g
     */
    
    public void gameScreen(Graphics g){
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        drawTitle(g);
        drawClouds(g);
        drawFieldAndHill(g);
        drawScoreBoard(g);
        drawHideBar(g);
        drawMoleHills(g);
 
         //saveBackground();  --------------------------------------WAS HERE----------------------------------------<
    }
            
    /**
     * painting the game screen
     * @param g
     */
    
    public void playing(Graphics g){
        
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        drawFieldAndHill(g);
        drawTitle(g);
        drawClouds(g);        
        drawScoreBoard(g);
        drawMole(g);
        drawHideBar(g);
        drawMoleHills(g);
               
    }
       
    /**
     * draws main title
     * @param g 
     */
    
    public void drawTitle(Graphics g){
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                              
        g2d.drawImage(title, 150, 70, null);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * draws scoreboard
     * @param g 
     */
    
    public void drawScoreBoard(Graphics g){
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                              
        g2d.drawImage(scoreBoard, 250, 200, null);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * draws clouds
     * @param g 
     */
    
    public void drawClouds(Graphics g){
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < clouds.length; i++){             //drawing clouds

            g2d.drawImage(clouds[i].getImage(), clouds[i].getX() + clouds[i].move(), clouds[i].getY(), this);

            if(clouds[i].getX() + clouds[i].movement == BOARD_WIDTH + 200){

                clouds[i].setMove();
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * draws bars to hide moles
     * @param g 
     */
    
    public void drawHideBar(Graphics g){
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        g2d.setColor(new Color(102,204,0)); 
        
        g2d.fillRect(0, 445, BOARD_WIDTH, 50);            //top part for upper moles
        
        g2d.fillRect(0, 605, BOARD_WIDTH, 80);            //middlepart for middle moles
        
        g2d.fillRect(0, 830, BOARD_WIDTH, 50);   //bottom part for lower moles
    }
    
    /**
     * draws mole hills
     * @param g 
     */
    
    public void drawMoleHills(Graphics g){
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < moleHill.length; i++){           //mole hills
            
            g2d.drawImage(moleHill[i].getImage(), moleHill[i].getX(), moleHill[i].getY(), this); 
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * draws hills and fields
     * @param g 
     */
    
    public void drawFieldAndHill(Graphics g){
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        g2d.setColor(new Color(30,179,0));                  //darker outlines
        g2d.drawOval(0, 300, BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);
        g2d.drawRect(-5, 500, BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);
        
        g2d.setColor(new Color(102,204,0));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 400, BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);            //hill and field
        g2d.fillOval(0, 300, BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);
    }
    
    /**
     * draws moles
     * @param g 
     */
    
    public void drawMole(Graphics g){
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        g2d.drawImage(mole.getImage(), mole.getX(), mole.getY() + mole.move(), this);
           

    }
    
    /**
     * saves the background
     */
    
    public final void saveBackground(){
        
        if(!backGroundFile.exists()){
            
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            try {

                Graphics2D graphic = image.createGraphics();  
                repaint();
                printAll(graphic); 

                ImageIO.write(image, "png", backGroundFile);
              

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                Logger.getLogger(Board.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * updates scoreboard with score
     */
    
    public void updateScore(){
        
        scoreBoardLabel.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
  

    /**
     * method to start the game process
     */
    
    public void playGame(){
                
        countDown();
         
        ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
           
            Runnable task = () -> {  
                
                mole = new Mole(35,790,0,0,false);
                inGame = true;  
                this.add(scoreBoardLabel); 
                scoreBoardLabel.setVisible(true);
                saveBackground();                       //NOW HERE-------------------------------------------<
                
                new Timer(10, new ActionListener(){
                    
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        
                        updateScore();
                        repaint();
                        
                        if(score >= 50){
                             
                            inGame = false;
                            repaint();
                            start.setVisible(true);
                            start.setText("NEXT LEVEL");
                            Mole.speed ++;
                            countdown = 3;
                            score = 0;
                            scoreBoardLabel.setVisible(false);
                            updateScore();                            
                            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }).start();
            };
            
            ex.schedule(task, 4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    }
    
    public void countDown(){
        
        this.add(countDownLabel);
        countDownLabel.setVisible(true);
        countDownLabel.setText(String.valueOf(countdown));       
        
        new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   
                countdown --;
                countDownLabel.setText(String.valueOf(countdown));                
                
                if(countdown == 0){
                    
                    countDownLabel.setText("GO");
                    
                }
                if(countdown == -1){
                    
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    countDownLabel.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }).start();      
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        
        if(mole.getBounds().contains(e.getPoint())){
            
            if(mole.isHit() == false){
                
                mole.hit();
                
                int level = mole.getOriginalY();
                
                switch(level){
                    
                    case 790:
                        
                        score += 5;
                        
                        break;
                        
                    case 580:
                        
                        score += 15;
                        
                        break;
                        
                    case 430:
                        
                        score += 25;
                        
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        
    }
    

    class play implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            start.setVisible(false);
            
            gameScreen = true; 
            start.setVisible(false);

            repaint();
                
            playGame();
   
            setCursor(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
            new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Mallet.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(400, 400, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH),
            new Point(0,0),"custom cursor"));;

        }
        
        
    }
    public static BufferedImage imageToBufferedImage(Image im) {
        
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage
           (im.getWidth(null),im.getHeight(null),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics bg = bi.getGraphics();
        bg.drawImage(im, 0, 0, null);
        bg.dispose();
        return bi;
  }
    
}
```

...

[what im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF3si.png)

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2DQ6.png)

Comment: A [mre] code post, one using images available from a website, would greatly help us in our efforts to figure out the cause of your exact problem.

Comment: Your code doesn't show a `JFrame` with a drawing `JPanel`.  Study the Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to see how it's done.

Comment: You create an empty image in method `saveBackground` with this line of code: `BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(...` Where do you actually draw into that image?

Comment: i didnt think that was necessary gilbert as it is a standard thing and it works fine the problem is the imported images are not saving to the created buffered image

Comment: its right below it abra, see "what im getting", the "what i want" is a screenshot of the painted panel in my program

Comment: Are you doing this on the first loading, or have you already displayed the image on the JPanel when you do it. There is something about the image observer and a buffered image, where the image might not be ready or finished drawing by the time you try to save. If you had a complete example with a JFrame + JPanel you might have a good question here.

Comment: If you look at [drawImage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,int,int,java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) you can see that it has the possibility to fail. You could check the return value if it is true then you should be ok.

Comment: matt sorry for the late reply, i have edited it to just include the main class(frame), and the jpanel class, you were correct! though i had loaded the jpanel with the images it wasnt ready for the buffered image, i had after this question was raised introduced a scheduled executor and that time delay was enough for the images to be ready, im sure someone can explain it better than that . but that solved it.

Comment: @matt just learnt to put the @ before the name, thank you.

Comment: @matt  hi matt sorry this is a bit old now, just wondering what you think of my solution, i had done it while ago, i meant to put it up when i did it but.. well distractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the image was not getting drawn is because [Graphics#drawImage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,int,int,java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) was not drawing the image.

To fix this, you will see in the methods for rendering the backgrounds I have created do while loops to check if the draw Image method returns true. Which would indicate that image has successfully been drawn.

...

```
 public void startScreen(Graphics g){
    
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    
    g2d.setColor(new Color(128,191,255));
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);   //blue sky
    
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(40, 40, 80, 80);   //sun
    
    g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW); 
    g2d.fill(circle);
           
    boolean cloudImage1 = false;
    boolean cloudImage2 = false;
    
    do{                         //start clouds
        
        cloudImage1 = g2d.drawImage(startclouds[0].getImage(), 90, 100, null);
        cloudImage2 = g2d.drawImage(startclouds[1].getImage(), 600, 100, null);
        
    }while(cloudImage1 == false || cloudImage2 == false);
    
    drawTitle(g);           //draws main title

    g2d.setColor(new Color(102,204,0));                 //green grass
    g2d.fillRect(0, 560, BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);
                    
    boolean fenceCheck1 = false;
    boolean fenceCheck2 = false;
    
    do{                         //draws fence
        
        fenceCheck1 = g2d.drawImage(fence, -105, 370, null);
        fenceCheck2 = g2d.drawImage(fence, fence.getWidth(null) / 2 + 8, 370, null);
        
    }while(fenceCheck1 == false);   //check image is loaded before save

    for(int i = 0 ; i < startMoles.length;){            //start screen moles
        
        boolean check = g2d.drawImage(startMoles[i].getImage(), startMoles[i].getX(), startMoles[i].getY(), null);
        
        if(check == true){          //check image is loaded before save
            
            i++;
        }
    }
      
    for(int i = 0 ; i < startMoleHills.length;){           //start screen mole hills

        boolean check = g2d.drawImage(startMoleHills[i].getImage(), startMoleHills[i].getX(), startMoleHills[i].getY(), this); 

        if(check == true){      //check image is loaded before save
            
            i++;
            
        }
    }

    boolean grassImage1 = false;
    boolean grassImage2 = false;
    boolean grassImage3 = false;       

    do{                                         //grass oimages
               
        grassImage1 = g2d.drawImage(grass, 100, 700, null);      //check image is loaded before save
        grassImage2 = g2d.drawImage(grass, 500, 650, null);      //check image is loaded before save
        grassImage3 = g2d.drawImage(grass, 600, 500, null);      //check image is loaded before save
    
    }while(grassImage1 == false || grassImage2 == false || grassImage3 == false);
    
    boolean flowerImage1 = false;
    boolean flowerImage2 = false;
    
    do{                                         //flower images
        
        flowerImage1 = g2d.drawImage(flower1, 50, 600, null);        //check image is loaded before save
        flowerImage2 = g2d.drawImage(flower1, 600, 700, null);        //check image is loaded before save
        
    }while(flowerImage1 == false || flowerImage2 == false);
    
}
```

...

this is the method to save the panel

...

```
public final void saveStartBackground(){
    
    if(!startBackGroundFile.exists()){
        
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        try {

            Graphics2D graphic = image.createGraphics();  

            startScreen(graphic);    

            ImageIO.write(image, "png", startBackGroundFile);


        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(Board.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

...

this is the method i use to start the save

...

```
  public void loadGame(){
    
    gamePlayMusic();
    saveStartBackground();
    saveBackground();
    saveEndBackground();
    gunShot();
    moleNoise();
    this.add(start);
}
```

...

which i call before the jframe is set to visible therefore ensuring the panels are all good to go before the game starts.

...

```
public class WhackAMole extends JFrame implements Sprites{

Board board = new Board();

public WhackAMole(){
   
    this.setSize(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setTitle("Whack-A-Mole");
    this.add(board);
    this.addMouseListener(board);
    
    board.loadGame();

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            new WhackAMole();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: It looks fine, it seems like a lot of information to show that you used a do/while loop with a pair of booleans to make sure the images get draw.

Comment: @matt, good! yeah i see what you mean, just so used to getting an answer to show more code on here i thought it would just be easier to show the complete code.   thanks for the feedback